# Saving scrollbars state/location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a panel where I dynamically add custom controls to it. If controls go out of the panels bounds, Horizontal/Vertical scrollbars automatically shows (`AutoScroll == true`) and scrollbars will follow the control via the following code:

```
if(panelDiagram.VerticalScroll.Visible || panelDiagram.HorizontalScroll.Visible) {
    panelDiagram.ScrollControlIntoView(tempNode);
}
```

This way, while moving the tempNode around, scrollbars will follow it.

Is there any way to preserve the state of the scrollbars when I load everything again from the database? I tried a lot of things like `ScrollControlIntoView(lastAddedControl)` but nothing is working. Maybe I have to turn off `AutoScroll` and manage everything by my hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Panel` is derived from `ScrollableControl` which exposes a few properties you might find useful:

- `AutoScrollPosition`
- `VerticalScroll`
- `HorizontalScroll`

It looks like `autoScrollPosition` is what you're after; it's a `Point` instance that contains the current X and Y scroll coordinates for each scrollbar. `X` will be zero if you're only doing vertical scrolling.

Save it like so:

```
public override void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    this.panel1.AutoScrollPosition = GetSavedScrollPoint();

}

public override void OnFormClosing(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    SavePointSomewhere( this.panel1.AutoScrollPosition );
}
```

Comment: Saving the AutoScrollPosition X,Y alone and loading it back doesn't do the job. I Could provide screenshots if necessary.

Comment: `AutoScrollPosition` is a struct, so you cannot set fields individually, you have to replace the struct instance entirely.

Comment: That wasn't the problem. I'm setting the AutoScrollPosition as a new Point(x,y) but the outcome is not right.

Comment: It turned out to be some other problem in the code that is causing the autoscroll problem. Location of controls gets changed when the scroll starts moving, I needed to adjust the location saved to the database with the AutoScrollPosition.